# an integral equation in a function with two arguments

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

Say we are given $C(s,t)=\min(s,t)+\zeta st$. How can we solve $$g(s,t)=C(s,t)+\lambda \int_0^1g(s,u)C(u,t)du.$$
Looking into some text books on integral equations I see that most of the kernels, $C$, that they exemplify are degenerate (separable) hence solving such an equation becomes easy. But how could one proceed in this case where the kernel is not separable?